# Join ID & Name from Two Separate Tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables...

```
Table 1 (keywordsTbl)
KeyID               Key_Name
================================
1                   Biology
2                   Entertainment

Table 2 (profileTbl)
Keyword_ID          Key_Name
================================
1(from keywordsTbl) Biology(from keywordsTbl)
2(from keywordsTbl) Entertainment(from keywordsTbl)
```

My query in profileTbl is indexing KeyID from the keywordsTbl and its working fine. The only problem is my output shows up like so (no array). :

[image]

Seems like its indexing only the 1st keyID... The results only show 1 single keyword even though there are more than one keyID being placed in the row:

[image]

My query looks as so:

```
include 'db.php'; 

   $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM profileTable, addKeywordTable ORDER BY LaName ASC");


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{

     $fname = $row['FirName'];
     $lname = $row['LaName'];
     $title = $row['Title'];
     $keys = $row['Keyword_Name'];
     $id = $row['source_ID'];

if(!in_array($title,array('',null)) && !empty($title)):
 $title = '('.$title.')';
 else:
 $title = '';
endif;
```

What's the easiest way to show an array when two tables are being used? Would a join work better in this case?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what your database *actually* looks like, but I *can* tell you that `["17","18","40"]` is not an array as far as MySQL is concerned, that's a string. If you could post a `SHOW CREATE` for the tables involved it would clarify matters.

Comment: Agreed - I wasn't considering that your `foreign key` was stored in a string *"array"* within the column Keyword_ID - is this a choice you are making and if so, can you undo that in favor of a proper relational approach?

Comment: you wrote in a comment : I am not receiving the error. Instead I am being delivered the keyID's and not the Keyword_Name's... that is my issue! ::: If you give your `$row['Keyword_Name'];` a wrong name it's normal . Should be `$keys = $row['Key_Name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that this is what you are asking, but if you want a list of results based on a join for `KeyID` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT p.Laname, p.FiName, GROUP_CONCAT(k.Key_Name)
FROM ProfileTable AS p
JOIN addKeywordTable AS k ON k.KeyID = p.Keyword_ID
GROUP BY p.LaName, p.FiName
```

If you want to include more files in the select list you need to add them to the `GROUP BY` list or use an aggregate function (`GROUP_CONCAT`, `MAX`, `MIN`, etc) on them in the select list.

Comment: Post what you are doing and what your error is? Not the comments on your question - is the Keyword_ID a string list of ID's?

Comment: @Matthew... i am not receiving the error. Instead I am being delivered the keyID's and not the Keyword_Name's... that is my issue!

Comment: @MizAkita Perhaps provide a SQLFiddle of your setup and some sample data and I will help you get it right: http://sqlfiddle.com/